# How to read the id field from SQLServer and show it on a MessageBox with C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

This my login page and it works but i can't read  the row `id` in my database
How can I read the `id` of the person that login and show him the value with a `MessageBox`?

```
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {



        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-TLOVFL6;Initial Catalog=testsqlinsert;Integrated Security=True");
      SqlDataAdapter da;
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form3 f3 = new Form3();
            this.Hide();
            f3.ShowDialog();
            this.Show();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT id,username,password FROM empdata Where username=@username AND password=@password", con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", textBox1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", textBox2.Text);


            SqlDataReader dr;
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            int c = 0;
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                c += 1;
            }
            if (c == 1)
            {


                Form4 f4 = new Form4();
                this.Hide();
                f4.ShowDialog();
                this.Show();
            }
            else if (c > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("duplicTE");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("USERNAME OR PASSWORD IS NOT CURRECT");
            }
            textBox1.Clear();
            textBox2.Clear();




            con.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for the help

Comment: Is `id` row the same row as `username` & `password` or  is it in a different row? Cause from your query it should read `id`.

Comment: You can follow these instructions: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You can also use dr[0] or dr["id"]